# Problems with Dynamic fom with JQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm doing an Invoice system, and i'm facing a problem.

Imagine a simple Invoice, where you have rows (lines, tuples, whatever) where you place the thing you're buying, the amount, the price, etc.

So, in my script i've a form like this:

```
<form action='I-process-the-form-but-not-see-data.php'>
   <input ... //some other imputs (client,date,etc)

   <table>
   //table hedaers
      <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='invoiceData[0][name]' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='invoiceData[0][amount]' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='invoiceData[0][price]' /></td>
   </tr>
</form>
```

I provide a button that adds a line to the invoice. I'm doing it with JQuery.

I first get the first  and clone it. Replace invoiceData[0] with invoiceData[COUNTER] (Global counter) and everything looks great.

The problem is that my data is not being sent to the php script. The only data i get is the inputs that are static (first loaded). Not the one that i add with jquery.

I've inspect it with firebug and it's adding the new lines ok.

Actually, if i paste the code generated by JQuery in the static form it sends it well.

What could be happening?

**EDIT (JQUERY MAGIC):**

```
var clon = $("#selectorForTR").clone().html(); //there is a minimal workaround for this but doesn't matters
clon = $(html.replace(/invoiceData\[0\]/ig, "invoiceData["+contador+"]"));
$("#tableBody").append(clon);
```

Comment: Please post your jquery code you are using, difficult to solve without it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with it I think Marc. Becouse the line is added correctly. Thanks anyway. I've posted the jquery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are opening and closing your cloned tr, i think that is why it is only getting one row.

```
<tr> ...html... </tr>
```

See my example : http://jsfiddle.net/wADef/

Changed it a bit to work in jsFiddle, but check it out and let me know.

Comment: I've checked and i'm closing the TR. Anyway, it's a form-input thing, then the only things that matters is if it's added anywhere between the <form> and </form> tags. Thanks Marc

Comment: I've solved it. I just moved the <form> tag. It is weird. Must be some kind of bug. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you are appending the generated html in the right place? ie, inside the form tag? If the data isn't coming through, that's the only thing I can think of immediately! :]

Comment: I'm not appending it in the form tag, but in the tbody tag, that is inside the form tag. So, yes, it's in there.

Comment: When I've dynamically changed form structure, I've not used the clone method. What happens if instead of cloning the html, you write it again using the new counter?